# Search in WinRT 8.1 over the Charms Bar

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Is there a way to preselect programmatically my own app if I using the Search charm in Windows 8.1 in my app. I dont want use the new Searchbox!

So I don't have to select first my app?

Thanks for answers

Gia

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the Search contract directly, then the Search charm will be scoped to your app by default, rather than to global search. Run the [Search contract sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5) and you'll see this in effect, and that sample has all the reference code you need to do the same.